# Is my lumia 635 unlocked?

Tags: lumia-635

I bought a Lumia 635 from AT&T (it is marketed as a GoPhone) that I am able
to use it with a regular AT&T sim card.

Under the "extra+info" section of my phone, SIM unlock 1.0.0.5 is listed as installed. Does that mean that I'm able to
use this with another GSM carrier overseas (outside of US)? or do i need to get another unlocked code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

AT&T go phones come locked. In order to unlock them, you must have service on that device for six months, then call customer support. It can be unlocked remotely.